# Sql Query to get details from second table

Tags: sql

I have two tables (see below). I am trying to get the details from second table where first and second table has same customer and also, i want to get a blank where first table customer is not in second table.

First table

`Table1
CUSTOMER   | COLOR
A          | YELLOW
B          | GREEN
C          | YELLOW
D          | GREEN
E          | GREEN
F          | RED
G          | GREEN
H          | RED
I          | RED`

`Table2
CUSTOMER | STATUS
A        | OPEN
C        | IN PROGRESS
D        | IN PROGRESS
F        | REOPENED
G        | OPEN
H        | IN PROGRESS
J        | OPEN
K        | OPEN`

`expecting results like below
CUSTOMER  |COLOR   |  STATUS
A         |YELLOW  |  OPEN
B         |GREEN   |
C         |YELLOW  |IN PROGRESS
D         |GREEN   |IN PROGRESS
E         |GREEN   |
F         |RED     |REOPENED
G         |GREEN   |OPEN
H         |RED     |IN PROGRESS
I         |RED     |`

if i use inner join, i am getting only matching values. I want blank where there is no customer from table1 in table b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select t1.*,
    t2.status
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.customer = t2.customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below query.

```
SELECT Table1.Customer, Table1.Color, Table2.Status
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Customer = Table2.Customer
ORDER BY Table1.Customer;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL LEFT JOIN operation returns all records from the left table irrespective of records matched against right table and the matched records from the right table.

As a solution please try executing following query is SQL shell.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 as t1
LEFT JOIN table2 as t2 ON t1.customer = t2.customer
ORDER BY t1.customer;
```